# Notepad++ insert "GO" between sql statements as new line

Tags: sql, notepad++

I have the following sql statements (1K plus)

```
insert into sodeny values('ABC',123,'USER')
insert into sodeny values('XYZ',123,'USER')
insert into sodeny values('EFG',123,'USER')
```

I am trying to insert "GO" as a new line using Notepad++ but can't seem to get it...is it possible? I need the result to look like this

```
insert into sodeny values('ABC',123,'USER')
GO
insert into sodeny values('XYZ',123,'USER')
GO
insert into sodeny values('EFG',123,'USER')
GO
```

I am trying to create a script to be executed against a legacy DB.

Comment: Do you mean you can't type it? (Is the file readonly?) Or do you mean you can't figure out the find/replace that'll do it automatically?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use an application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simply repalce newlines with GO like this

search: `\n`
replace: `\nGO\n`

yes as Joe commented you have to use extended mode to search for newlines (refer also to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133965/find-crlf-in-notepad))

Comment: Make sure that the Search Mode is set to Extended

Comment: currently GO is not present...I am trying to add that as a new line....when replacing...I tried find \n replace with \n GO but couldn't get it...that's why I was asking if it was possible.

Comment: Got it...it's the other way around find \n and replace with GO\n!

Answer (score 3):

What you actually want is:

```
Find what     : \n
Replace with  : \nGO\n
```

<sub>Note: two \n's, as prefix and suffix</sub>

At the bottom

```
Match whole word only (unticked)
Mach case             (unticked)
Wrap around           (unticked)

Search mode   : Extended (\n, \r.....)
```