# Remove double spacing

Tags: regex, notepad++

Sometimes, copy pasting code from my email makes everything have an extra blank line.

For example

```
1: hi
2:
3: hello
4:
```

Is there a way to target these empty lines with regex and delete them?
I'm using notepad++ with the search(with regex) and replace capability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<del>Because Notepad++ regex operates only line by line, without a multi-line mode, you can't remove entire lines with regex alone.</del> This is no longer true as of Notepad++ 6.0, which now uses PCRE as its regex engine and allows for multi-line replacements. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133989/106224) for more info.

The TextFX plugin that Notepad++ ships with allows you to remove blank lines without using regex. Just highlight your entire document (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and do **TextFX > TextFX Edit > Delete Blank Lines**. If your selection or document begins and/or ends with a blank line though, those lines won't be removed automatically — but removing those is just a matter of:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>
2. <kbd>Del</kbd>
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>
4. <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

To remove double spacing in Notepad++ (I'm using v7.8.4) go to: `Edit`, `Line Operations`, `Remove Empty Lines`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have notepad++, but the regular expression "^$" (without the quotes) matches only blank lines.  Perhaps notepad++ will allow you to replace matches of that regular expression with the empty string, thus removing the blank lines.

Comment: When i do this, it says "The regular expression search is formed badily"

Comment: I'd suggest something like `^\s*$` if you were to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

- Search > Replace...

Search Mode = Extended

Find what : `\r\n\r\n`

Replace with : `\r\n`