# Notepad++ newline Regex Issues

Tags: regex, notepad++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find CRLF in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133965/find-crlf-in-notepad)

I am trying to use notepad++ for some simple regex find and replace.  But when I try to use the regular expression syntax for a new line (\r\n) I get the folowing error:

> can't find the text: "\r\n"

\r\n works in "Extended" search and in other text editors, but not in the Regular Expression search.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `[\r\n]+` instead? Order of return/new line may be reversed. Placing them in a class insures they match (in either order) but in succession. (Alternatively, you can use `[\r\n]{1,2}` to find single instances of the return.)

Comment: @bazmegakapa you're right, I just didn't see it because they used CRLF rather than \r\n

Answer (score 5):

<del>Notepad++'s regex engine doesn't support multiple lines, so newline characters can't be matched. If you need to find and replace blank lines, you need to use extended search.</del> This is no longer true as of Notepad++ 6.0, which now uses PCRE as its regex engine and allows for multi-line replacements. See [the accepted answer to the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133989/106224) for more info.

Comment: According to a post in [June 2008](http://markantoniou.blogspot.com/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html) the regex engine appears to acknowledge `\r`,`\n` (among others including `\t`, `\b`, etc.). -- EDIT: Also found [this post](http://markantoniou.blogspot.com/2009/02/regular-expressions-guide.html) mentioning to use `ctrl+Q,ctrl+J` to insert a new line in the pattern field.

Comment: @Brad Christie, there are 3 search modes: normal, extended, and RegEx. The normal mode is *normal*, the extended mode allows newlines tabs and a few other selectors, and the RegEx mode is allows for a limited regex search.

Comment: @Brad Christie: I never got that to work. Re your edit, isn't that for emacs?

Comment: @zzzzBov: Ah, that may be the different, need to use extended. @BoltClock: Try the `ctrl+Q,ctrl+J`. I'm kind of curious if that works.

Comment: It has an "emac equivalent", so I just assume it works for both. I may be wrong (I personally use notepad2 over notepad++, so (unfortunately) I can't test, and thus I'm not posting any answer(s).)

Answer (score 4):

From Notepad++ help file:

> Because Notepad++ makes use of the Scintilla regex engine, it is the same as with SciTE, so a full list of regex options can be found here (with the difference that POSIX mode is always on, this is not an option): http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html

---

From SciTE docs:

> Note that \r and \n are never matched because in Scintilla, regular expression searches are made line per line (stripped of end-of-line chars).

Comment: hmm if this is the case, does anyone know of any good free text editors for windows that support RegEx with end-of-line chars?

Comment: New in version 7, [EditPad Lite](http://www.editpadlite.com/) now features regex search-and-replace.  I've been using EditPad **Pro** for years, and it has the best regex support I've ever seen in an editor.

Answer (score 2):

From Notepad++ original replace options, *"Extend"* mode support `\r\n`, so you can just replace every *newline* to an unique short string that never appeared in your document, e.g. `abcdefg`, to make a huge one line string. Then you can do your regex replace job in the *"Regex"* mode, try to keep the unique tag string, replace `\r\n` back using *"Extend"* mode, done, inconvenient, and stupid.