# How to remove linebreaks and replace them with a comma in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need some help in Notepad++ and regular expressions.

Example how it looks at the moment:

```
aaaaa
bbbb
cccccc
```

How I want it (remove breakpoints and replace them with a comma and a blank space):

```
aaaaa, bbbb, cccccc
```

I was told that I can do it by checking "Regular expression" and "matches newline" and;

```
Find what: "[\r\n]+"

Replace with:","

-> Replace All
```

However I can't find the "matches newline" in my Replace window. Do I need any plugins for it? The version of my Notepad++ is 5.7 (UNICODE).

Comment: Check this solution, this should help !

http://stackoverflow.com/a/133989/1268844

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the `Extended` search mode, replacing `\r\n`  with   `,`

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: +1 for the image :) this works also if you use *Regular expression* mode, not only in *Extended* search

Comment: Yes, the image was really helpful! It seems it doesn't work when I check the Regular expression instead. Anyway, the Extended search worked, and that's enough for me:)

Comment: In other editors I've used with similar interface (e.g., Textpad) I have just entered \n as the string to find, so that if A B and C are all on separate lines and I find/replace \n with , I end up with A,B,C on one line. With Notepad++ when I do the same thing without adding in the \r, I still get 3 lines, just with a comma before the B and a comma before the C.  Is there any preset combination for Notepad++ that combines the \r and \n?

Answer (score 7):

Not much complications are required for removing linebreaks using `notepad++`

Just select from `end of line to the start of next line` and press CTRL + H,
you will get the text to replace and then replace it with `,` or your desired character