# I need a regex to repair lines split at column 80

Tags: regex

Problem - Multiline, Semi-colon delimited file has been split at column 79 or 80 (not always the same for some strange reason).

It seems to me that a Regex would be the appropriate solution, so now I have two problems.

Lines are:

```
1sdf.............................mno[cr][lf]
pqr........xyz......................[cr][lf]
.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|[cr][lf]
2sdf.............................mno[cr][lf]
pqr........xyz......................[cr][lf]
.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|[cr][lf]
3sdf.............................mno[cr][lf]
pqr........xyz......................[cr][lf]
.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|[cr][lf]
4sdf.............................mno[cr][lf]
pqr........xyz......................[cr][lf]
.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|.....|[cr][lf]
... 10000 rows ...
```

Where the pipe is a non-space whitespace character (possibly a tab)

I need:

```
1sdf.............................mnopqr........xyz......................[cr][lf]
2sdf.............................mnopqr........xyz......................[cr][lf]
3sdf.............................mnopqr........xyz......................[cr][lf]
4sdf.............................mnopqr........xyz......................[cr][lf]
```

I managed to get the job done with

**Pass 1:** 
Replace `^\s*\r\n` with `\rxxx\n`

// Replace Blank lines with \rxxx\n leaving

```
1sdf.............................mno[cr][lf]
pqr........xyz......................[cr][lf]
[cr]xxx[lf]
2sdf.............................mno[cr][lf]
pqr........xyz......................[cr][lf]
```

Pass 2:
Replace `\r\n` with [empty] 
//leaving:

```
1sdf.............................mnopqr........xyz......................[cr]
xxx[lf]
2sdf.............................mnopqr........xyz......................
```

Pass 3:
Replace `\rxxx\n` with `\r\n`

//leaving:

```
1sdf.............................mnopqr........xyz......................[cr][lf]
2sdf.............................mnopqr........xyz......................
```

And the rest of the cleanup is trivial.

Is there any way of doing this in a single step?  The output is from a common financial application, and I'd rather be able to fix the files myself rather than try and get many multiple clients to adjust their output.

Comment: does replacing `\r\n\s*((\r\n)?)` with captured group no. `1` not work? (If you tell us which engine/technology you are using I could possibly test it myself and post it as a proper answer ;))

Comment: Nope.  It replaces all newlines, and leaves me with one single line. I'm playing with it in notepad++, but I can adjust flavours as required.

Comment: I just tested it, it works with a minor caveat. Let me write an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++ (using regular expression mode) you can use this:

Find what: `\r\n(\s*\r\n)?`

Replace with: `\1`

Then run "Replace All" exactly once. However, [**make sure you update to Notepad++ 6**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133989/1633117)! Otherwise matching `\r\n` with a regular expression won't work in Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `^\s*\r\n` match the line you want to remove as you said above, I believe you could do it with replacing `\r\n\s*\r\n|\r\n` by `\r\n`

It's my first regex, so if it doesn't work, don't be to harsh :-)

Good luck

Comment: This won't remove the first of every three `\r\n` as requested.

Comment: @m.buettner I expect it to be remove. That's the reason for the pipe followed by the additional `\n\r`

Comment: It matches the first `\r\n`, but it does not get replaced. You replace the `\r\n` after the pipe by `\r\n` which just leaves it in place.