# Find LF (line feed) in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hi can find a line that ended with LF (line feed) in notepad++ ? I only want to find a line that ended with LF without CR. Example on below, the search should only return the line 15xxxxxKL office staff.

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search this with a regex like `^[^\r\n]*\n`.

However, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133965/find-crlf-in-notepad/133989#133989), the ability to use `\n` in regular expression mode was introduced in Notepad++ 6.0. Before this version, you'd have to use the extended search mode (where you can not use a regex).

Comment: if use .*\n it will returned all line that ended in LF. In my case I only want to returned those lines that have LF without CR

Comment: I don't think the dot covers the carriage return character. You can also try `[^\r]*\n`.

Comment: The dot matches the CR except with notepad++ (strange behavior). `[^\r]*\n` will not work because `[^\r]` contains the LF. You need to exclude it from the class too, otherwise `[^\r]*` may match several lines: `[^\r\n]*\n`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Also in Java, unless you set the `UNIX_LINES` flag, the dot does not match the CR.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this regex:

```
^.+?(?!\r)\n
```

**Explanation:**

```
^       : begining of line
.+?     : one or more any character (not greedy)
(?!\r)  : negative look-ahead to make sure there is not a carriage return
\n      : line feed
```