# Select text using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to select a para of javascript using regex. I need to replace the value with something else, so I am using a Notepad++ editor to do this job. It is a big file which contains this script multiple times. My code is something like this that I want to select :-

```
<ins class="thisisfirstscript"
     style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
     data-client="ABCD"
     data-slot="4397140188"></ins>

<ins class="thisissecondscript"
     style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
     data-client="CDEF"
     data-slot="4496122889"></ins>
```

I want to select each of them separately. You can see `data-slot` is different for both cases. So, I want to consider it to select. I am trying with,

```
<ins class="thisisfirstscript"(.*?)data-slot="4397140188"></ins>
```

&

```
<ins class="thisissecondscript"(.*?)data-slot="4496122889"></ins>
```

But, it is not working. Since, new line character is not including here.

Working answer is :-

```
/(?:<ins class="thisissecondscript")([\s\S]*)?(?:data-slot="4496122889"><\/ins>)/
```

Now, second is, suppose, I have same script multiple times. It looks like,

```
<ins class="thisisfirstscript"
         style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
         data-client="ABCD"
         data-slot="4397140188"></ins>

    <ins class="thisissecondscript"
         style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
         data-client="CDEF"
         data-slot="4496122889"></ins>

<ins class="thisisfirstscript"
         style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
         data-client="ABCD"
         data-slot="4397140188"></ins>
```

Now, you can see `class="thisisfirstscript"` is repeated two times. So, when I am using the answered regex it is selecting from first `class="thisisfirstscript"` to third `class="thisisfirstscript"` , that means, `class="thisissecondscript"` is also including. But, I want to select just particular `class="thisisfirstscript"`

Comment: You really need to use a HTML parser in this case.

Comment: Actually, I want to replace the value of it with something else. So, that I am using text editor to select and replace with new code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find CRLF in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133965/find-crlf-in-notepad)

Comment: Maybe this could be a clue for you https://regex101.com/r/rK5oJ2/1

Comment: What about: `<ins class="thisisfirstscript"(.*\n\s+){1,100}data-slot="4397140188"><\/ins>`?

Comment: @HonzaHejzl [Your pattern doesn't work](https://regex101.com/r/rK5oJ2/2)

Comment: @Shafizadeh Please post this as answer. It is working, I will approve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/(?:<ins class="thisissecondscript")([\s\S]*)?(?:data-slot="4496122889"><\/ins>)/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rK5oJ2/1)

---

**Edit:** According to updating the question, try this one:

```
/(?:<ins class="thisisfirstscript")([\s\S]*?)(?:data-slot="4397140188"><\/ins>)/gm
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tT1qE2/2)

Comment: I have one more question. I have same script repeated multiple times. SO, when I am using it, it is selecting from start and end to all the other parts between them. Is there any other way that it will select only particular part at different places?

Comment: Your question is kinda vague for me, I cannot understand it .. You have to create a new question on stackoverflow and ask your new question *(by a good explanation plus a few details)*

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question with explanation. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.