# Excel : how to paste data in one column?

Tags: excel, windows

lets say we have following data:

[image]

When I try to paste this into Excel, the selection windows occupies two columns:

[image]

Why? Is there a way to fix this? I want only one column!

Comment: CR LF is a new line character that you re copying from notepad++, i guess. It's a blank space basically. Replace it with nothing and then copy. Refer to this answer to how to do that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133965/find-crlf-in-notepad

Comment: *Why* probably because some excel interpretation of ";".  *Is there a way to fix this?* by removing the ";". Also note that such question is off-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel considers `;` as a column separator. This is why.

You can replace this by going on excel `DATA` tab, then on `Text to column`, choose `Delimited` and on the next screen, uncheck `Semicolon` and Finish.

This will disable semicolons as column separator when you paste it.

Comment: how can he replace in excel when he wants to copy in excel?

Comment: The replace I mean the "; means column separator" so excel wont consider it a character that means column separator.

Comment: You mean after I copy in excel, I do a text to column?

Comment: You have to do it once before you paste. Just type some gibberish, go to text to column and uncheck the semicolon. Finish, then paste the data you want

Comment: Don't you think replacing the semicolon in the text before copying would be simpler?

Comment: Maybe he/she needs the semicolon on the pasted data.